# Why do i get an exception with an Array on device but not in simulator?

Tags: ios, runtime-error, nsset

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'

Why do i get this exception in iPhone 5.1 and not in the 6.0 simulator when i run the code below? This code is for a slide view controller is this supported in 5.1?

```
- (NSArray*)controllers {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (self.centerController) [result addObject:self.centerController];
    if (self.leftController) [result addObject:self.leftController];
    if (self.rightController) [result addObject:self.rightController];
    if (self.topController) [result addObject:self.topController];
    if (self.bottomController) [result addObject:self.bottomController];
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
}
```

I think this is what Kevin is looking for.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

IIViewDeckController* deckController = [self generateControllerStack];
self.leftController = deckController.leftController;
self.centerController = deckController.centerController;

/* To adjust speed of open/close animations, set either of these two properties. */
// deckController.openSlideAnimationDuration = 0.15f;
// deckController.closeSlideAnimationDuration = 0.5f;

self.window.rootViewController = deckController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

- (IIViewDeckController*)generateControllerStack {
LeftViewController* leftController = [[LeftViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftViewController" bundle:nil];
RightViewController* rightController = [[RightViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RightViewController" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *centerController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
centerController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerController];
IIViewDeckController* deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerController
                                                                                leftViewController:leftController
                                                                               rightViewController:rightController];
deckController.rightSize = 100;

[deckController disablePanOverViewsOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView")];
return deckController;
}
```

Comment: Difficult to troubleshoot without knowing what those viewControllers are. Probably difference in the way the master view controller (are you using ViewDeck?) and the child view controllers are being init'ed on the device but difficult to know without seeing the init code.

Comment: That's not the cause of your problem, an `NSSet` is. Show us where you are populating an `NSSet`.

Comment: @JaiGovindani Yes this is ViewDeck.

Comment: @Kevin By NSSet are you referring to NSObject used for the controllers?

Comment: No, by NSSet I mean exactly what I said, [NSSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). What does the rest of your stack trace look like?

Comment: I just checked out ViewDeck (https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/tree/master/ViewDeck). The only set in there is _disabledPanClasses (in IIViewDeckController.m). Did you call the disablePanOverViewsOfClass: method anywhere?

Comment: @Kevin 

2013-07-13 09:28:07.957 ViewDeckExample[3221:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13cc022 0x10c1cd6 0x1374a48 0x13749b9 0x13d6c6d 0x1aa84 0x2bdb 0x2839 0x222386 0x223274 0x232183 0x232c38 0x226634 0x21d8ef5 0x13a0195 0x1304ff2 0x13038da 0x1302d84 0x1302c9b 0x222c65 0x224626 0x2685 0x2585)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Comment: @AhmedMohammed No I have not called "disablePanOverViewsOfClass:" will check it out now.